# How to delete empty data.frame in a list after subsetting in R

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe

Suppose I'm subsetting from a `list` of named `data.frame`s with respect to a subsetting variable called `long`.

After subsetting, some `data.frame`s in the `list` may be empty because there is no match for subsetting in them.

I was wondering how I could delete **all such empty `data.frame`s** in my final output.

A simple example, and my unsuccessful solution are shown below:

```
b <- list(Study1 = data.frame(d = 6:8, long = c(F, F,F)), Study2 = data.frame(d = 9:11, long = c(T, T, F)) )


( h <- lapply(b, subset, subset = long) ) ## subset with respect to "long"

## OUTPUT:

   $Study1
   [1] d    long
    <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)   ## This data.frame is empty!! must be deleted ##!

   $Study2
    d long
    1  9 TRUE
    2 10 TRUE


## I tried the following with no success: ##

for(i in 1:2) if(nrow(h[[i]]) == 0) h[[i]] <- NULL else h[[i]]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply `Filter` by number of rows:

```
new_list_of_dfs <- Filter(NROW, list_of_dfs)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `keep`

```
library(purrr)
keep(h, ~ nrow(.x) > 0)
#$Study2
#   d long
#1  9 TRUE
#2 10 TRUE
```

---

Or use `sapply` from `base R` to create a logical condition and `Extract` the `list` elements

```
h[sapply(h, nrow) > 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by **akrun** works but to understand why your last line of code didn't work (`for(i in 1:2) if(nrow(h[[i]]) == 0) h[[i]] <- NULL else h[[i]]`): this is because you're deleting an element of your list before the loop can finish.  So, save your query in an index first, and then use the results of that query to delete the elements in a second line.  More verbose but more learning for you:

```
index <- vector(mode = 'logical', length = length(h)) #initialize index as all FALSE
for (i in 1:length(h)) { #this is your last line of code, modified
  if(nrow(h[[i]]) != 0) {
    index[i] <- TRUE
    } else {next} 
}
h <- h[index]
```